# Woocommerce add-to-cart URL with product bundle

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am following [this guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/) in order to use an add-to-cart URL to add a bundled product to my cart. My goal is to bundle 4 products into ONE and using the add-to-cart URL for this purpose:

Looking at the solution, it seems quite trivial to construct such a link and I am quite sure I did it correctly:

```
https://myshopurl.com/cart?add-to-cart=77229&quantity[6674]=1&quantity[7214]=1&quantity[5780]=1&quantity[5892]=1
```

In this case, `77229` is the ID of the bundled product while `6674`, `7214`, `5780` and `5892` are single products that I want to bundle into `77229`

I get as far as adding the products into the cart all together but they are not bundled. It seems that the bundled product is ignored in this case.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but something is not working as expected.
Is there any best practise on how to solve this problem? Do I need to add custom code to `functions.php` to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the solution for Grouped Products, which are not the same as Product Bundles. With Product Bundles, you add the products you want bundled using the Product Data meta box in the editor. At this point, you may be able to use a simple add-to-cart URL if you are bundling simple products. I haven't tested this. If you are bundling variable products, the add-to-cart URL becomes complicated. See https://www.alternativeradio.org/products/alem002-alem001/ for an example:

`https://www.alternativeradio.org/products/alem002-alem001/?add-to-cart=11061&bundle_variation_id_61=5266&bundle_attribute_pa_format_61=mp3&bundle_variation_id_62=5262&bundle_attribute_pa_format_62=mp3`

I don't even remember how I reverse engineered this.

Comment: For optional bundle product, which has the ID=1133, we can use `?add-to-cart=1122&bundle_selected_optional_1133=1&bundle_quantity_1133=1` (May, 2022).